# Model itself and nested Meta use the same list

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.5**

The problem with this code is that I have already created a list in the model (comment "Field list created"). Then in Meta nested class I'd like to use the same list.

Is it possible not to create the list twice?

**utils.py**

```
def get_distinctive_fields():
    """
    By these fields a people can be distinguished
    from one another.
    """

    field_list = ['last_name_ru',
                  'premarital_surname_ru',
                  'first_name_ru',
                  'patronymic_name_ru',
                  'nickname_ru',
                  'year_of_birth', ]

    return field_list
```

**models.py**

```
class Person(LoginRequiredMixin,
             models.Model):

    def get_composed_string(self):

        composed_string = ""

        field_list = get_distinctive_fields() # Field list created.

        for field in field_list:
            composed_string += value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_composed_string()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = get_distinctive_fields() # Failed to use already created list.
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. `get_composed_string` is an instance method, which can only be called once you have an instance; but `unique_together` is a class-level attribute (of the nested class, but still) which will be called at definition time. And why would you need `unique_together` to be dynamic anyway?

Comment: I just use the same list twice. It is not dynamic. But I want to write the field list only once (maybe later want to change it).

Comment: Not sure what's not working in this case, but have you tried declaring the list as a constant rather than a method? i.e. `DISTINCT_FIELDS = [...]` and then using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways of tackling this. In the first place, you could use a constant for the list of distinctive fields instead of a method. i.e. `DISTINCTIVE_FIELDS = [...]`

On the other hand, you can define the distinctive fields in the Meta class, and then use that in your `get_composed_string` method. Something like

```
def get_composed_string(self):
    return " ".join(self.Meta.unique_together)
```

If you don't need this `get_composed_string` for anything other than `__str__`, you can do it directly in the `__str__` method...